# Trying to use pelican to change my theme but not really working

Tags: web, static, generator, blogs, pelican

I am trying to add to my blog this theme: `https://github.com/limbenjamin/voce` but somehow I do all the steps but the website is not looking anything like it should be. This is the `pelicanconf.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
from __future__ import unicode_literals

AUTHOR = u'John Homer'
SITENAME = u'John Homer'
SITEURL = ''

OUTPUT_PATH = 'content'

THEME = 'voce'                          # make sure path points to folder where you cloned the theme
DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = "%b %d, %Y"                 # short date format, optional but recommended 
USER_LOGO_URL = "http://i.imgur.com/zzCRZUH.jpg"  # change URL to point to desired logo for site
```

Well at least the things I changed in it.

[image]

And this does not look like anything it should look like...